# Python regex to match subreddit names

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm just learning python and trying to pull subreddits out of a file with a regex, but not having much luck..

```
import re

string1 = "asdf asdf 587985 (*&(*& /r/whatever3/fjfjfjjrr /r/whatever2 jfdnhkjv43$#$"
matches = re.search(r"/r/+(\S)+[/ ]", string1)
if matches:
    print matches.groups()
```

Doesn't seem work work properly at all, though the syntax looks correct to me (it should match a string without whitespace (\S) followed by a space or a forward slash [/ ]

This version might be matching 'whatever3' -- it returns the 3 which is the last character at least:

```
import re

string1 = "asdf asdf 587985 (*&(*& /r/whatever3/fjfjfjjrr /r/whatever2 jfdnhkjv43$#$"
matches = re.search(r"/r/+(\S)+/", string1)
if matches:
    print matches.groups()
```

I'm also having trouble figuring out from the docs how I pull the variable (like the subreddit name itself) out of the match..

Comment: Try putting the `+` inside the `(\S)` so it becomes `(\S+)`

Comment: @Jon, that also returns the string after the subreddit name: ('whatever3/fjfjfjjrr',) -- and only matches one of the two subreddits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(\S)+` captures the last repetition of `\S`. Use  `(\S+)` instead to capture all the non-spaces.

The above includes intervening slashes. To exclude them, change `\S` to `[^\s/]`.

```
>>> re.findall(r"/r/([^\s/]+)", string1)
['whatever3', 'whatever2']
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will match any string prefixed with `/r/`, but we can be a lot stricter than that.

Reddit's site says this if you enter an invalid subreddit name during creation:

> Community names must be between 3–21 characters, and can only contain letters, numbers, or underscores

Furthermore, I noticed that a subreddit name cannot begin with an underscore, and that not all users use the leading slash in `/r/` (`r/`). Here is a regex that matches only *valid* subreddits, starting `/r/` or `r/`:

```py
regex = r"\/?r\/([a-z0-9][_a-z0-9]{2,20})(?:\Z|\s)"
```

[Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/YigHNm/2). Here, we are also using a non-capturing group with `\Z`, which indicates the end of a string, in addition to `\s`, which indicates any whitespace.

If the desire is just to validate a single subreddit name without the prefix, the regex is simpler:

```py
regex = r"^([a-z0-9][_a-z0-9]{2,20})$"
```

[Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/12tR6W/1).